# How can I position an text to an exactly position

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align an text to an exactly position, like 2cm from right not the pre-stabled positions like right, left and center. There's an example: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u3bN.png)
How can I center the Regular, upgraded and exclusive cases like that?

Comment: those are set to text align center.  the [$#] blocks are inline with the centered text, which is why it appears to not be centered...but it is if you include those elements

Comment: i didn't understood anything

Comment: i outlined further in the answer i submitted.  since the example you posted is just a screen shot, i had to go on best guess.

but judging on the screen shot, my answer, with additional styling, should accomplish what the screen shot is reflecting

Comment: you need to post code

Answer (score 0):

per my comment, here is how the text is centered, but the price tag is included as an inline element with the text.

html

```
<p class="container">
  Text goes here
  <span class="block">
    $3
  </span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.block {
  padding: 4px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

EDIT:

based on the additional information you provided, it's not just aligning text that you were having an issue with, but also layout in general.

I've updated my example to show how you could align elements within a container using `text-align: center;` and converting the different text/price items to have `display: inline-block;`.

This is just an entry point to get you started.  There are many other ways to layout content with CSS, from floats, flex-box and new CSS Grids.  I suggest you review each to determine what is appropriate for your project.

Updated Demo: https://codepen.io/scottohara/pen/oWLxXN

Comment: do you know why if i change the font/color the text won't align anymore in any way?

Comment: Changing the font or color should have no effect on alignment. Sounds like you may have an error in your CSS. If you post code, it can be reviewed

Comment: Sorry. I can't help you any further if you don't post your code. Screen shots aren't enough info.

Comment: hey i posted the code just look up man @scottohara both css and html

Comment: didn't see that you had posted the code as an answer to your own question.  you might want to delete that and add it as an edit to your original question.  i'll take a look now though.

Comment: I have updated my answer, which should give you what you need in the short term, but as I mentioned in my answer, you should look further into CSS properties to appropriately lay out your UI.

good luck